# Click events not working on Apple devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, events

So I have a web page that whenever you click into an image it show up in a bigger form.

The code is simple (obviating the rest of the code)

```js
open_image.addEventListener("click", () => open_image());
```

```html
<div id="click-me">
  <img src="img_test.jpg">
</div>

<div id="bigger-img" style="display: none">
  <img src="img_test.jpg">
</div>
```

What open_image() function does is simply setting display block to the hidden image

This works without problems in PC and android devices, but for apple mobiles devices such as iPad or iPhone the click event seems not to be listened or is like its ignoring it.

I've searched for solutions and seems like in CSS the property cursor: pointer should work, but not for me, after setting this property to the body keeps ignoring the click event.

Any ideas for these apple devices?

Comment: Don't you want to use a [pointer event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events) instead? It works for mouse, pen, and touch events. See: [_"The HTML5 Pointer Events API: Combining touch, mouse, and pen"_](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-pointer-events-api-combining-touch-mouse-and-pen)

Comment: Are you sure that the click event doesn't fire? To me, it sounds like a CSS issue

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: simply do `open_image.addEventListener("click", () => aleret(1));` to check it fires or not, css has nothing to do with onclick event, `cursor: pointer` affects desktop cursor that renders when you hover on element - if you add that to body you will have `pointer (hand)` cursor for whole website

Comment: The click event fires correctly excepet in apple mobile devices, i will try the pointer event

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl just tried the pointer event open_image.addEventListener("pointerdown", () => open_image()); and the event still not firing in iPhone (android and desktop opens it normally)

Answer (score 0):

use "touchend" in addition to the click event
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchend_event

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33612414)